# Detect Keystrokes within input tags within an iframe embed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a website that has a bunch of forms embedded on it on different pages. I need to be able to detect keystrokes within input tags inside of those iframes, then make sure that if keystrokes were detected and a user attempts to leave the page, they are stopped & prompted so that they don't lose data that they had input into the form.

I had it working when a certain element on the page had a certain class, which works ok, but it often times would pop up when a user was just on a page & had the iframe loaded, but I need it to only happen if a user has typed in the iframe.

I tried the following but it isn't working for me.

```
notifyTab = false;
$('#notify', $('iframe.wufoo-form-container').contents()).on('keyup', function(e) {
    notifyTab = true;
    console.log(notifyTab);
});

jQuery(window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
    if(notifyTab == true){
        console.log('true - run jq event'); 
        // Cancel the event
        e.preventDefault();
        // Chrome requires returnValue to be set
        e.returnValue = 'Your Notify Form is open! Make sure you clicked "Submit", otherwise you may lose your message!';
    }
}));
```

Comment: I worked on an asynchronous page where we looked for input similarly and we ended up using the onchange event instead of the keyup.  The keyup happens for each character of field input - which can be excessive, could be the user overwriting data with the same data, or could be the user entering data before deleting the data back to a blank field, etc.  The onchange reduced our triggers with the same results.

Comment: Why do you need an iframe in the 1st place?

Comment: The user is interacting with multiple forms throughout the site, all of which are made usable via iframe, they're forms that were created using a separate web tool (wufoo), and have to be embedded via iframe.